# How can I echo correctly using mySQL on a php web page?

Tags: php, mysql

I got a problem in querying an information in mySQL, here's the code:

```
SELECT avatar FROM amcms_users WHERE username='admin'
```

and the result is '**59da6ceb5c74ac98f317a4b4af3c72f6.jpg**' which is correct.

Now when I load it on php page using these php codes...

```
<?php
$locAvatar = mysql_query("SELECT avatar FROM amcms_users WHERE username='admin'");
echo $locAvatar;
?>
```

and the result is wrong, '*Resource id #27*'

How can I echo it correctly? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch the data first, by using the `mysql_fetch_*` functions:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT avatar FROM amcms_users WHERE username='admin'");
$locAvatar = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)["avatar"];
echo $locAvatar;
```

(`mysql_fetch_assoc` fetches into an array)

Comment: I tried it but I guess I'm not doing it well. I am not good with this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the results and then echo them. The resource (which is a reference to the results) that [`mysql_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) returns is to be passed on to one of the `mysql_fetch_` series of functions. These functions dereference the result and return the data in the appropriate format.

Have a look at:

- [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)
- [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)
- [`mysql_fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

Comment: Refer Femaref's answer, or the links that I have listed in my answer. They should help you.